# emacs: How to make header line of SQL results always visible, and follow horizontal-scroll?

Tags: emacs, resultset, multiple-columns, horizontal-scrolling

I use emacs for pretty much everything I can, including running SQL command-line sessions in a shell-mode buffer.

SEEKING:

Make the SQL result-set header (column names) appear at the top of the visible portion of the window even when the actual header from the SQL client output has scrolled out of view.
  Further, make the header scroll horizontally to remain aligned with the data columns.

ATTEMPT:

I have been able to wrangle the header-line (via the `window-scroll-functions') such that when the SQL result set header scrolls off the top of the window I set the buffer window's header-line to the SQL result set header.

That effectively keeps the data columns labeled when scrolling vertically, but when scrolling horizontally the header-line does NOT follow the horizontal scroll position (akin to mode-line which also does not normally scroll horizontally, thankfully).

The next thing I wanted to do is have the header-line scroll horizontally as well. So, instead of using `window-scroll-functions' - which does not fire for horizontal scroll [bug???] - I switched to using `post-command-hook' which fires after every command (perhaps overkill no?). This works ... kind-of.

PROBLEM:

Here is the problem, the header-line does not snap into correct position until after an additional command is executed (e.g. "C-e" alone does not cause the header line to snap to, but when followed by "C-b" the snap to happens). It **seems** like the post-command-hook is being executed AFTER the command, but BEFORE the window is redrawn (which seems kinda weird in the case of commands where the window may be expected to change). Specifically, (window-hscroll) definitely returns the hscroll position as it was BEFORE the command.

CODE:

To avoid clutter, I won't post the actual code I'm using to set the header-line (unless someone is interested in seeing it), but I will post this sample elisp that can demonstrate that the hscroll position has the value from before the command is run:

```lisp
(defun pch-demo ()
  "post-command-hook: Demonstrate that the window hscroll
 value is not updated before this hook is run."
  (interactive)
    ;; the following message demonstrates that we are getting the
    ;; hscroll position as it was PRIOR to running the command
  (message "hscroll=%S" (window-hscroll))
  )

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'pch-demo t t)
;; doesn't make much sense with line-wrapping on
;;(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

DEMO STEPS:

1. open a buffer
2. make sure line truncation is ON
3. make the window narrow enough (or lines long enough) that some lines get truncated
4. go to the beginning of a long line and hit C-e
5. notice that the message says "hscroll=0"
6. hit C-a
7. notice that the message says "hscroll=SOMETHING_NOT_EQUAL_TO_ZERO"

QUESTIONS:

1) Is there a better approach (i.e. not using emacs' header-line)? Something from org-mode maybe???

2) Using my approach, does anyone know how I can get the updated window positions in my hook function?

Thanks superbunch!

Comment: `shell-mode`? So you're not using the in-built `M-x sql-DBNAME` interfaces / `sql-interactive-mode`?

Comment: I did something similar (`sync-window`). In the command loop the `post-command-hook` are run directly after the execution of the commands. Only thereafter emacs checks whether the commands sent point out of view and corrects the scroll (in both directions). You need to hook both `post-command-hook` AND `window-scroll-functions`. `post-command-hook` for simple point motion which keeps point in view (therefore no scroll and no scroll functions) and `window-scroll-functions` if the window is scrolled because point went out of view.

Comment: `window-scroll-functions` doesn't seem to get invoked on a horizontal scroll (as far as I can tell in my attempts to use it). Perhaps considered a bug in emacs??? I tried to modify the emacs source code, but in my feeble-minded and brief attempt, I couldn't find the right place or mechanism to invoke the window-scroll-functions upon horizontal scrolling. Also, does anyone else think that the post-command-hook should be getting the value of `window-hscroll` AFTER the effects of the command are completed? (Note in my post, I mention it gives the `window-hscroll` from BEFORE the command).

Comment: phils: FYI: I use a home grown (and awesome, by the way;) perl program for all of my database interactions ... hopefully I will have the time soon to clean it up for open-source release.